# getopts won't call twice in a row?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

For some reason the options work fine the first call of `lib_progress_bar -c "@" -u "_" 0 100`, but on the second call and beyond everything is default because it seems like `getopts c:u:d:p:s:%:m: flag` isn't true the second time around, or atleast the case is never executed when I used `set -x`

```
#!/bin/bash



lib_progress_bar() {
    local current=0
    local max=100 
    local completed_char="#"    
    local uncompleted_char="."  
    local decimal=1 
    local prefix=" ["
    local suffix="]"
    local percent_sign="%"
    local max_width=$(tput cols)

    local complete remain subtraction width atleast percent chars
    local padding=3

    while getopts c:u:d:p:s:%:m: flag; do
        case "$flag" in
            c) completed_char="$OPTARG";;
            u) uncompleted_char="$OPTARG";;
            d) decimal="$OPTARG";;
            p) prefix="$OPTARG";;
            s) suffix="$OPTARG";;
            %) percent_sign="$OPTARG";;
            m) max_width="$OPTARG";;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))


    current=${1:-$current} 
    max=${2:-$max} 


    if (( decimal > 0 )); then
        (( padding = padding + decimal + 1 ))
    fi


    let subtraction=${#completed_char}+${#prefix}+${#suffix}+padding+${#percent_sign}
    let width=max_width-subtraction


    if (( width < 5 )); then
        (( atleast = 5 + subtraction ))
        echo >&2 "the max_width of ($max_width) is too small, must be atleast $atleast" 
        return 1 
    fi


    if (( current > max ));then
        echo >&2 "current value must be smaller than max. value"
        return 1
    fi

    percent=$(awk -v "f=%${padding}.${decimal}f" -v "c=$current" -v "m=$max" 'BEGIN{printf('f', c / m * 100)}')

    (( chars = current * width / max))

    # sprintf n zeros into the var named as the arg to -v
    printf -v complete '%0*.*d' '' "$chars" ''
    printf -v remain '%0*.*d' '' "$((width - chars))" ''

    # replace the zeros with the desired char
    complete=${complete//0/"$completed_char"}
    remain=${remain//0/"$uncompleted_char"}

    printf '%s%s%s%s %s%s\r' "$prefix" "$complete" "$remain" "$suffix" "$percent" "$percent_sign"

    if (( current >= max )); then
        echo ""
    fi
}


lib_progress_bar -c "@" -u "_" 0 100 
echo
lib_progress_bar -c "@" -u "_" 25 100
echo
lib_progress_bar -c "@" -u "_" 50 100
echo

exit;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add:

```
local OPTIND
```

at the top of your function.

Comment: I use `OPTIND=0` after my getopts-while-loop and shift. I didn't know about the `local OPTIND` trick, but the zero-reset should work if you are strangely calling `getopts` more than once in the _same function_.

Answer (score 14):

To explain why Dennis's answer works, see the `bash` man page (search for `getopts`):

> OPTIND is initialized  to  1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked.
>
> The shell does not reset OPTIND automatically; it must be manually reset between multiple calls to getopts within the same shell invocation if a new set of parameters is to be used.

This is how `getopts` can process multiple options.

If `getopts` didn't maintain global state in the `OPTIND` variable, each call to `getopts` in your `while` loop would keep processing `$1`, and never advance to the next argument.