# Using getopts inside a Bash function

Tags: bash, function, getopts

I'd like to use `getopts` inside a function that I have defined in my .bash_profile.
The idea is I'd like to pass in some flags to this function to alter its behavior.

Here's the code:

```
function t() {
    echo $*
    getopts "a:" OPTION
    echo $OPTION
    echo $OPTARG
}
```

When I invoke it like this:

```
t -a bc
```

I get this output:

```
-a bc
?
```

What's wrong?  I'd like to get the value `bc` without manually shifting and parsing. How do I use `getopts` correctly inside a function?

EDIT: corrected my code snippet to try $OPTARG, to no avail

EDIT #2: OK turns out the code is fine, my shell was somehow messed up.  Opening a new window solved it. The arg value was indeed in $OPTARG.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

As @Ansgar points out, the argument to your option is stored in `${OPTARG}`, but this is not the only thing to watch out for when using `getopts` inside a function. You also need to make sure that `${OPTIND}` is local to the function by either unsetting it or declaring it `local`, otherwise you will encounter unexpected behaviour when invoking the function multiple times.

`t.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo()
{
    foo_usage() { echo "foo: [-a <arg>]" 1>&2; exit; }

    local OPTIND o a
    while getopts ":a:" o; do
        case "${o}" in
            a)
                a="${OPTARG}"
                ;;
            *)
                foo_usage
                ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

    echo "a: [${a}], non-option arguments: $*"
}

foo
foo -a bc bar quux
foo -x
```

Example run:

```
$ ./t.sh
a: [], non-option arguments:
a: [bc], non-option arguments: bar quux
foo: [-a <arg>]
```

If you comment out `# local OPTIND`, this is what you get instead:

```
$ ./t.sh
a: [], non-option arguments:
a: [bc], non-option arguments: bar quux
a: [bc], non-option arguments:
```

Other than that, its usage is the same as when used outside of a function.

Comment: 1.) The `1` in `1>&2` is not necessary. 2.) You missed to define `a`, `o` and `OPTARG` as local. 3.) The `exit` will not exit the script but just a sub-shell. In order to exit the script it is necessary to `set -e` in the outer shell and `exit 1` in the sub-shell. The example does not trigger the problem, but a `MSG=$(foo ...)` will do it.

Comment: @ceving 1) This is a matter of coding style but, no, it's not necessary as per the language definition. 2) Agreed, those should be local. 3) As you said, the exit *will* exit the script in my example. Of course `exit` won't exit sub shells but this is not a specific problem to this question. You don't have to use `set -e`, you just have to make sure to catch the error and `MSG=$(foo ...) || die` works just as well. `set -e` is one solution to the problem  [but it's not idiot-proof](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and I, as many others, don't recommend using it.

Comment: Just pointing out that even if you're not using OPTIND in the function (e.g., with `shift;`), it still needs to be localised in order to have predictable behaviour.

Comment: @ceving, you can look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566331/why-is-optind-messing-my-positional-params - I added `local` but did not helped

Comment: I asked Gemini Advanced a similar question and it got it wrong - I am glad to stumble upon this that helped me.

Answer (score 20):

Here is simple example of [`getopts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopts) usage within shell function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
t() {
  local OPTIND
  getopts "a:" OPTION
  echo Input: $*, OPTION: $OPTION, OPTARG: $OPTARG
}
t "$@"
t -a foo
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh -a bc
Input: -a bc, OPTION: a, OPTARG: bc
Input: -a foo, OPTION: a, OPTARG: foo
```

As [@Adrian pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16655341/55075), `local OPTIND` (or `OPTIND=1`) needs to be set as shell does not reset `OPTIND` automatically between [multiple calls to `getopts`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048326/55075) (`man bash`).

The base-syntax for `getopts` is:

```
getopts OPTSTRING VARNAME [ARGS...]
```

and by default, not specifying arguments is equivalent to explicitly calling it with "$@" which is: `getopts "a:" opts "$@"`.

In case of problems, these are the used variables for `getopts` to check:

- `OPTIND` - the index to the next argument to be processed,
- `OPTARG` - variable is set to any argument for an option found by `getopts`,
- `OPTERR` (not POSIX) - set to 0 or 1 to indicate if Bash should display error messages generated by the `getopts`.

Further more, see: [Small getopts tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) at The Bash Hackers Wiki

Comment: Very thoughtfully laid out answer. I don't know if it works, but great job.

Comment: @kenorb, you can look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566331/why-is-optind-messing-my-positional-params, added `local` but did not helped

Answer (score 6):

The argument is stored in the varable `$OPTARG`.

```
function t() {
  echo $*
  getopts "a:" OPTION
  echo $OPTION
  echo $OPTARG
}
```

Output:

```
$ t -a bc
-a bc
a
bc
```

Comment: Sorry I incorrectly pasted my code snippet... I also echo $OPTARG, that's the 3rd line which is blank.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Magnus Probably because you called the function several times and `$OPTIND` isn't defined locally (see Adrian's answer). While I'm grateful that you accepted my answer, you should probably rather accept his instead.

Comment: The code works only when pasting into shell, but not in the script.

Comment: @kenorb It works just fine from a script. I'm not making this up.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure how `t` is called, I had to call as `t -a bc` inside the script or add `t "$@"`, initially I thought it's going to work without.