# Which shells automatically resets OPTIND when entering a function?

Tags: shell, standards, getopts

Some shells automatically resets the `OPTIND` variable used `getopts` when entering a function, some not.

For instance *GNU bash 3.2.57(1)* does not reset the `OPTIND` variable when it enters a function while *zsh 5.0.5* does.

Which shells automatically resets `OPTIND` when entering a function?  What is the behaviour recommended by POSIX?

Comment: Using `getopts` to operate over function arguments? Are you resetting `OPTIND` to 1 before trying to use getopts in the function?

Comment: Your problem might be variables locality. You must declare local `OPTIND` (if you're using `getopts` both in the script and the function). check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16654607/3374591

Comment: Yes this is the intended use. I do not reset `OPTIND` before. That's interesting, it seems that zsh resets `OPTIND` when it enters the function while bash does not. At least for the versions mentioned.

Comment: And check out http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/getopts.html

Comment: @all Thank you, these are useful bits of information!