# getopts not working inside .bashrc

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a file:

*argtest*

```
#!/bin/bash

function parse ()
{
    echo "in parse"
    echo "starting to parse args $@"

    while getopts "pq:" opt; do
        echo "parsing arg $opt"

        case "$opt" in
            p)  echo "got option p" ;;
            q)  echo "got option q with value ${OPTARG}" ;;
        esac

    done
}

parse "$@"
```

That performs correctly:

```
balter$ bash argtest -pq 9
in parse
starting to parse args -pq 9
parsing arg p
got option p
parsing arg q
got option q with value 9
balter$ source argtest
in parse
starting to parse args
balter$ parse -pq 9
in parse
starting to parse args -pq 9
parsing arg p
got option p
parsing arg q
got option q with value 9
```

However, if I have the same function in my `~/.bashrc` file, I get:

```
balter$ tail -16 ~/.bashrc
function parse ()
{
    echo "in parse"
    echo "starting to parse args $@"

    while getopts "pq:" opt; do
        echo "parsing arg $opt"

        case "$opt" in
            p)  echo "got option p" ;;
            q)  echo "got option q with value ${OPTARG}" ;;
        esac

    done
}

balter$ source ~/.bashrc
balter$ parse -pq 9
in parse
starting to parse args -pq 9
```

I do notice something weird about `getopts`:

```
balter$ getopts
getopts: usage: getopts optstring name [arg]
balter$ which getopts
which: no getopts in (<other paths>:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/condor/bin)
```

**EDIT**
HA! Found the solution here [Using getopts inside a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654607/using-getopts-inside-a-bash-function?rq=1)

This works:

```
function parse ()
{
    echo "in parse"
    echo "starting to parse args $@"

    local OPTIND
    local OPTARG
    local opt

    while getopts "pq:" opt; do
        echo "parsing arg $opt"

        case "$opt" in
            p)  echo "got option p" ;;
            q)  echo "got option q with value ${OPTARG}" ;;
        esac

    done
}
```

If anyone wants to explain the `local` issue, I'd love to hear. Furthermore, if anyone wants to explain the `which getopts` thing, I'd love to hear that to.

Comment: Does the line  involving setting `export PATH` appear before the function definition or after in `.bashrc`

Comment: @Inian Before the function. What do you get with `which getopts`?

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the path elsewhere in `.bashrc`, because the problem seems to be it could not find the path where `getopts` is installed, at the instance when you are running the function.

Comment: Turns out it's finding getopts (somehow). The problem was local variables!

Comment: Nice that you have caught it, but I am closing this question to post as duplicate of the one you shared, so that you don't attract opinionated answers (or) spam here.