# Create shell command that parses arguments in function

Tags: bash

I am unable to parse flags in a function in a bash script.

I have a shell script `admin.sh` that I'm sourcing (i.e. `source ./admin.sh`).  In that script I have function called `command_to_do`. The code below shows what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want to be able to call `command_to_do` from the command line and process all arguments

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function command_to_do() {
  echo "Args $@"

  SYSTEM=false
  UNINSTALL=false
  PUSH=false
  VERSION="debug"

  while getopts "sup:" opt; do
    printf "\n$opt\n"
    case $opt in
      s) echo "Setting SYSTEM to true"
         SYSTEM=true
         ;;
      p) echo "Setting VERSION to $OPTARG"
         PUSH=true
         VERSION=$OPTARG
         ;;
      u) echo "Setting UNINSTALL to true"
         UNINSTALL=true
         ;;
    esac
  done

  printf "\nSystem: $SYSTEM\nVersion: $VERSION\n"

  if [[ $UNINSTALL = true ]]; then
    if [[ $SYSTEM = true ]]; then
      echo "system uninstall"
    else
      echo "non-system uninstall"
    fi
  fi

}
```

I'm getting very strange results.  The first time I run the `command_to_do -s -p release`, it correctly processes the flags and prints the expected results

```
Args -s -p release

s
Setting SYSTEM to true

p
Setting VERSION to release

System: true
Version: release
```

Every time after that, it doesn't seem to capture the flags. For instance, running that same command again gives:

```
Args -s -p release

System: false
Version: debug
```

If I remove the function declaration (`function command_to_do() {}`) and just have the code in the `admin.sh` file, everything seems to work fine every time, but I have to call the script with the dot syntax (`./admin -s -p release`). The reasoning behind why I don't want to use the dot syntax is not important. I just want to know if it's possible to do what I'm attempting and how.

I've read about passing the arguments to the function with `command_to_do $@`, but, as I'm trying to call the function by it's name from the command prompt, this is not applicable and it appears by the `echo $@` statement that the arguments are being passed to the function.
I'm new to writing bash scripts so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, using the `function` keyword is not particularly good practice; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete. On its own, it's a ksh compatibility feature; combined with POSIX-y `()` syntax, it's compatible with neither legacy ksh function declaration syntax *or* POSIX function syntax.

Comment: As another aside, `command_to_do $@` is just as buggy as `command_to_do $*`, and in exactly the same ways; to pass everything through *correctly*, you need quotes: `command_to_do "$@"`.

Comment: ...to speak directly to the question, though -- it's *very* unclear how you're getting the function declaration into your active shell, and *which* command line you want it to parse. If you mean the active command line in the calling shell, this might actually be one of the rare cases when an alias is the right tool. `command_to_do_fn() { ... }; alias command_to_do='command_to_do_fn "$@"'` -- but that's only true in very specific circumstances, and it's unclear to me whether those circumstances apply.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy to clarify, I'm using the mac terminal. I'm using the command `source ./admin.sh` to be able to call the `command_to_do` function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is resetting `OPTIND`, which tells `getopts` where it is in the current argument list. As it is, your first call leaves `OPTIND` at a value telling `getopts` not to process the arguments it already saw.

See a demonstration at https://ideone.com/UvUyn2

Comment: Thanks for the code sample!  I added the line `unset OPTIND` to the beginning of the function and it works perfect.  Any clarification as to why I don't need to unset the index if this code is not in a function?

Comment: If it's a separate script, it has its own variables.

Comment: In a function, it's better to declare `OPTIND` as local, so you won't interfere with the top-level script (or other functions, or...). See: [Using getopts inside a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654607/using-getopts-inside-a-bash-function).

Comment: Oh, shoot -- that's a proper duplicate.